# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' in Python

Tags: python, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate an integer and a string in Python, but I'm encountering a TypeError. Here's the code snippet:
number = 5
message = "The number is: " + number
print(message)

I expected the output to be "The number is: 5", but I'm getting the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'."
number = 5
message = "The number is: " + number
print(message)
ERROR Message:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Convert to string with `str` function before concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Python doesn't consider your number as text,
therefore it can't merge it with other text.
You can simply declare your number variable as text:

```py
number = '5'
```

Or if you want your variable to still be a number, you can convert it when you merge it with text:

```py
message = "The number is: " + str(number)
```